# Do I write "as large as one of" or "as large as the one of"

Tags: expressions

If I describe an animal and want to write about the leg of this animal compared to another, what is right/better:

This animal has got a leg which is as large as one of a tiger.

This animal has got a leg which is as large as the one of a tiger.

My son wrote the first sentence in an article and his teacher corrected it.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This animal has a leg as large as that of a tiger - that’s how I would write. “One of a ther” sounds very unusual.

The “got” is unnecessary, and so is the “which”.

Comment: Please don't answer obviously off-topic questions.

Answer (score 1):

More concisely still, "a leg as big as a tiger's".